# Revert the mocked module back to the original

Tags: elixir

I’m working with elixir and am seeing confusing/undesirable behavior when using Mox.

I just want to use a mock for a single test module. Let’s say I have 2 tests. Here is sample code:

```
defmodule MyTest do
  setup_all do
    defmock(DateTimeMock, for: DateTimeApi)

    :ok
  end

  test "test1" do
    {:ok, expected_datetime, _} = DateTime.from_iso8601("2019-09-08T00:00:00.000000Z")
    expect(DateTimeMock, :utc_now, fn _ -> expected_datetime end)
  end

  test "test2" do
    expect(something else)
  end
end 

defmodule MyTest2 do
  setup_all do
    defmock(DateTimeMock, for: DateTimeApi)

    :ok
  end

  test "test1" do
  end

  test "test2" do
  end
end
```

When MyTest2 runs I will see the error: (Mox.UnexpectedCallError) no expectation defined

Defining a mock for a single test ‘leaks’ out and affects all tests.

Does Mox have a way to revert the mocked module back to the original module after the test has finished?

Comment: This question looks identical to https://elixirforum.com/t/resetting-mox-mock-after-a-single-test/26435. Are you unsatisfied with the answers given there?

Comment: looking for fresh air and new ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [`on_exit`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/master/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#on_exit/2) callback in the `setup` block.  The main part of the setup function runs *before* each test (so it reads the current value), then the `on_exit` callback runs *after* each test (so it can set things back to their original values).

```
defmodule MyTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  setup do
    date_time_api = Application.get_env(:my_app, :date_time_api)
    on_exit(
      fn ->
        Application.put_env(:my_app, :date_time_api, date_time_api)
      end
    )
  end

  # Tests, fixtures follow...
end
```

Remember that it is important that your code defers to the run-time configuration available in the Application, so your code might look something like this:

```
def utc_now do
  Application.get_env(:my_app, :date_time_api).utc_now()
end
```

With a corresponding config value of something like

```
# config/config.exs or env-specific config file
config :my_app, date_time_api: DateTimeApi
```

That's what makes the whole thing work because the app will resolve the module name (i.e. the real one or the mock one) at run-time.

Comment: Very nice explanation. I can now much better understand the whole picture. Thank you. It explains everything. Nice!